# How to add HTML code in DNN (from client side i.e., editable mode) with external css file (eg in assets folder)

Tags: html, dotnetnuke

I want to add html code (as a client) using dotnetnuke.
For that I also require css which is too big.
Is there a way that I add html code and refer to external custom css file which is stored in **assets** folder?
If not, then how should i (the client user of dnn and NOT developer/designer) add html code along with external file css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways an external CSS file could be added without adding it directly to the Theme/Skin.

1. Page Specific - 
   Add the  tag referencing the css file uploaded to the site in the Page Header Tags: In DNN v9+, this is
   located in Page Settings -> Advanced -> S.E.O. -> Page Header Tags
   textarea.
2. Site wide - Add the  tag referencing the css file uploaded to the site in the HTML Page Header Tags: Settings -> Site Settings -> Site Behavior -> Default Pages -> HTML Page Header Tags
3. Site wide (CSS import) - Import the CSS file in the site's Custom CSS: Settings -> Custom CSS.

Note that you will need to include the portal/site ID in your link to the CSS file. 
(for example: '/Portals/0/Assets/my-styles.css', where '0' is the ID of the portal/site.

While you could easily add it to the module settings as suggested by Andrew, doing it as described this way would add the  element to the page headers or import through a CSS file as opposed to putting the  element in the middle of the HTML content.

Answer (score 1):

Dotnetnuke has a HTML module component, for this type of thing.

However, depending on what content filters are applied to this module settings, it may strip out CSS / style tags / comments etc.

**In an ideal world and CSS / Styling should be added to the DNN Skin.**

If you are adding a small 3rd party component, which is isolated / separated from the skin - One thing that I do is add items such as Script or External Style tags to the "Header" / "Footer" area of that HTML module:

[image]

If you add anything into this section, it won't be stripped out from the system.

This also can be used for negative purposes - Sites which have been compromised often will have malicious scripts added to these sections.